# Python Fit Arbitrary Gaussian Functions - Bad Fits?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to generalise some code to be able to fit multiple (n from 1 to >10) gaussian curves/peaks within a single dataset.

Using Scipy Optimise Curve_fit I can get pretty good fits when I hard code functions for 1-3 gaussians, and I've managed to produce functions which run without error for a generalise, arbitrary number of gaussians. However, the output fit is very poor. This is despite giving the input parameters which are identical to those used to generate the 'raw' data - i.e. a best case scenario.

Also, there is a non-zero chance the specific function may need to be modified from a simple gaussian at some point, but for now it should be OK.

Below is my code example, and the output figure is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy 
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

amp1 = 1
cen1 = 1
sigma1 = 0.05

df=pd.DataFrame(index=np.linspace(0,10,num=1000),columns=['int'])

def _ngaussian(x, amps,cens,sigmas):
    fn = 0
    if len(amps)== len(cens)== len(sigmas):
        for i in range(len(amps)):
            fn = fn+amps[i]*(1/(sigmas[i]*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*\
            (np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cens[i])/sigmas[i])**2)))
    else:
        print('Your inputs have unequal lengths')
    return fn



amps = [1,1.1,0.9]
cens = [1,2,1.7]
sigmas=[0.05]*3

popt_peaks = [amps,cens,sigmas]
df['peaks'] = _ngaussian(df.index, *popt_peaks)

# Optionally adding noise to the raw data
#noise = np.random.normal(0,0.1,len(df['peaks'])) 
#df['peaks'] = df['peaks']+noise

def wrapper_fit_func(x, *args):
    N = len(args)
    a, b, c = list(args[0][:N]),list(args[0][N:N*2]),list(args[0][2*N:3*N])
    return _ngaussian(x, a, b, c)

def unwrapper_fit_func(x, *args):
    N = int(len(args)/3)
    a, b, c = list(args[:N]),list(args[N:N*2]),list(args[2*N:3*N])
    return _ngaussian(x, a, b, c)

popt_fitpeaks, pcov_fitpeaks = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, *popt_peaks: wrapper_fit_func(x, popt_peaks), 
                       df.index, df['peaks'], p0=popt_peaks,
                       method='lm')


df['peaks_fit'] = unwrapper_fit_func(df.index, *popt_fitpeaks)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1.set_xlim(0,3)
ax1.plot(df.index, df['peaks'], "b",label='ideal data')
ax1.plot(df.index, df['peaks_fit'], "g",label='fit data')
ax1.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image: Bad Curve Fitting of Three Gaussians]

If you're interested, the context is in analytical chemistry, nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) and Fourier transform ion cyclotron resonance mass spectrometry (FTICR MS) signal processing.

Comment: I suggest first fitting a single peak, for example by using "index=np.linspace(0,1.25,num=1000)". After that is working, then try two peaks and then finally all three. I personally got a bad fit to a single peak using your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/, disclosure: I am a lead author) useful for this.  It provides an easy-to-use Model class for modeling data, including builtin Models for Gaussian, Voigt, and similar lineshapes making it easy to compare model functions.

Lmfit models can be added (or mulitplied) to make a Composite Model, making it easy to support 1, 2, 3, etc Gaussians and include different baseline functions as well.   There are docs and several examples at the link above.    A small rewrite of your example (including adding a bit of noise) might look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit.models import GaussianModel

amp1 = 1
cen1 = 1
sigma1 = 0.05

df=pd.DataFrame(index=np.linspace(0,10,num=1000),columns=['int'])

def _ngaussian(x, amps,cens,sigmas):
    fn = 0
    if len(amps)== len(cens)== len(sigmas):
        for i in range(len(amps)):
            fn = fn+amps[i]*(1/(sigmas[i]*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*\
            (np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cens[i])/sigmas[i])**2)))
            fn = fn+np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.05)
    else:
        print('Your inputs have unequal lengths')
    return fn

amps = [1.30, 0.92, 2.11]
cens = [1.10, 1.73, 2.06]
sigmas=[0.05, 0.09, 0.07]

popt_peaks = [amps,cens,sigmas]
df['peaks'] = _ngaussian(df.index, *popt_peaks)

# create a model with 3 Gaussians: pretty easy to generalize
# to a loop to make N peaks
model = (GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') +
         GaussianModel(prefix='p2_') +
         GaussianModel(prefix='p3_') )

# create Parameters (named from function arguments). For
# Gaussian, Lorentzian, Voigt, etc these are "center", "amplitude", "sigma"
params = model.make_params(p1_center=1.0, p1_amplitude=2, p1_sigma=0.1,
                           p2_center=1.5, p2_amplitude=2, p2_sigma=0.1,
                           p3_center=2.0, p3_amplitude=2, p3_sigma=0.1)

# Parameters can have min/max bounds, be fixed (`.vary = False`)
# or constrained to a mathematical expression of other Parameter values
params['p1_center'].min = 0.8
params['p1_center'].max = 1.5

params['p2_center'].min = 1.1
params['p2_center'].max = 1.9

params['p3_center'].min = 1.88
params['p3_center'].max = 3.00

# run the fit
result = model.fit(df['peaks'], params, x=df.index)

# print out the fit results
print(result.fit_report())

# plot results
plt.plot(df.index, df['peaks'],     'o', label='data')
plt.plot(df.index, result.best_fit, '-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.gca().set_xlim(0, 3)
plt.show()
```

This will produce a fit plot like this:
[image]

and print out a report of

```
[[Model]]
    ((Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')) + Model(gaussian, prefix='p3_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 102
    # data points      = 1000
    # variables        = 9
    chi-square         = 6.88439024
    reduced chi-square = 0.00694691
    Akaike info crit   = -4960.49871
    Bayesian info crit = -4916.32892
[[Variables]]
    p1_amplitude:  1.29432022 +/- 0.00428720 (0.33%) (init = 2)
    p1_center:     1.09993745 +/- 1.9012e-04 (0.02%) (init = 1)
    p1_sigma:      0.04970776 +/- 1.9012e-04 (0.38%) (init = 0.1)
    p2_amplitude:  0.91875183 +/- 0.00604913 (0.66%) (init = 2)
    p2_center:     1.73039597 +/- 6.7594e-04 (0.04%) (init = 1.5)
    p2_sigma:      0.09054027 +/- 7.0994e-04 (0.78%) (init = 0.1)
    p3_amplitude:  2.10077395 +/- 0.00533617 (0.25%) (init = 2)
    p3_center:     2.06019332 +/- 2.0105e-04 (0.01%) (init = 2)
    p3_sigma:      0.06970239 +/- 2.0752e-04 (0.30%) (init = 0.1)
    p1_fwhm:       0.11705282 +/- 4.4770e-04 (0.38%) == '2.3548200*p1_sigma'
    p1_height:     10.3878975 +/- 0.03440799 (0.33%) == '0.3989423*p1_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, p1_sigma)'
    p2_fwhm:       0.21320604 +/- 0.00167179 (0.78%) == '2.3548200*p2_sigma'
    p2_height:     4.04824243 +/- 0.02582408 (0.64%) == '0.3989423*p2_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, p2_sigma)'
    p3_fwhm:       0.16413657 +/- 4.8866e-04 (0.30%) == '2.3548200*p3_sigma'
    p3_height:     12.0238006 +/- 0.02922330 (0.24%) == '0.3989423*p3_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, p3_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(p3_amplitude, p3_sigma)     =  0.622
    C(p2_amplitude, p2_sigma)     =  0.621
    C(p1_amplitude, p1_sigma)     =  0.577
    C(p2_sigma, p3_sigma)         = -0.299
    C(p2_sigma, p3_amplitude)     = -0.271
    C(p2_amplitude, p3_sigma)     = -0.239
    C(p2_sigma, p3_center)        =  0.226
    C(p2_amplitude, p3_amplitude) = -0.210
    C(p2_center, p3_sigma)        = -0.192
    C(p2_amplitude, p3_center)    =  0.171
    C(p2_center, p3_amplitude)    = -0.160
    C(p2_center, p3_center)       =  0.126
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need.